# Como faço para calcular o perímetro de um triângulo no java?

Tags: java

Como faço para calcular o perímetro de um triângulo no java? 
Não sei como calcular o perímetro de um triangulo no java, alguém sabe? Já tentei mas não consegui, me ajudem!

Comment: Poste o código que você tem até agora, informe se é um método pra calcular o perímetro só passando os valores ou é algo mais complexo

Comment: Qualquer tipo de triângulo? coloque o código fonte mesmo errado, e detalhe o problema.

Comment: Para calcular o perímetro de um triângulo é só somar os lados dele. Como fazer isso em Java depende muito de como está a sua classe Triangulo. Poste ela aqui que fica mais fácil de ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Triangulo {

    private final double lado1;
    private final double lado2;
    private final double lado3;

    public Triangulo(double lado1, double lado2, double lado3) {
        this.lado1 = lado1;
        this.lado2 = lado2;
        this.lado3 = lado3;
    }

    public double getPerimetro() {
        return lado1 + lado2 + lado3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Triangulo [lado1=" + lado1 + ", lado2=" + lado2 + ", lado3=" + lado3 + "]";
    }

}
```